# POST http://localhost:8080/server2_0_war_exploded/user returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, gson

Hi there I am getting this error when try to create a user, hope someone can help. Other functions work like a charm but not this one.
There is a Client and a server.

Thank you in advance :D

createUser() in the Client Controller

```
public void createUser() {
    JsonObject data = new JsonObject();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input your firstname");
    data.addProperty("firstname", input.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Input your Lastname");
    data.addProperty("lastname", input.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Input your Email");
    data.addProperty("email", input.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Input your Username");
    data.addProperty("username", input.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Input your Password");
    data.addProperty("password", input.nextLine());

    data.addProperty("usertype", "0");

    Connection.postUser(data);


}
```

PostUser() in Client Connection Class

```
public static String postUser(JsonObject data) {
    ClientResponse clientResponse = HttpRequests.post("/user/", Crypter.encryptDecryptXOR(new Gson().toJson(data)));

    String response = null;

    if (clientResponse == null) {

        System.out.println("Error on SDK");
    } else {
        response = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
        if (clientResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
            System.out.println(response);
        } else
            System.out.println("error");
    }
    clientResponse.close();
    return response;

}
```

Post method in Client HttpRequests class

```
public static ClientResponse post(String path, String data) {
    ClientResponse clientResponse = null;

    try {

        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://localhost:8080/server2_0_war_exploded")
                .path(path);

        clientResponse = webResource.accept("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, data);
    }
    catch
            (UniformInterfaceException | ClientHandlerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return clientResponse;
}
```

Post method Server endpoint

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")


public Response create(String data) throws Exception {
    String s = new Gson().fromJson(data,String.class);
    String decrypt = Crypter.encryptDecryptXOR(s);
    if (controller.addUser(decrypt)) {
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .entity("{\"message\":\"Success! User added\"}")
                .build();

    }
    else return Response.status(400).entity("{\"message\":\"failed\"}").build();
}
```

Prepared statement in Server DbConnection class

```
public boolean addUser(User u) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement addUserStatement =
            conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users (First_Name, Last_Name, Username, Email, Password, Usertype) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    try {
        addUserStatement.setString(1, u.getFirstName());
        addUserStatement.setString(2, u.getLastName());
        addUserStatement.setString(3, u.getUsername());
        addUserStatement.setString(4, u.getEmail());
        addUserStatement.setString(5, u.getPassword());
        addUserStatement.setBoolean(6, u.getUserType());

        addUserStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Input to Api

Welcome to the mainmenu

You have the following choices

Login

Create user

2

Input your firstname

Christoffer

Input your Lastname

Palsgaard

Input your Email

Chris@chris.com

Input your Username

pals

Input your Password

1234

error

Error when i try to debug Client Connection class line 132

```
        if (clientResponse.getStatus() == 200) { clientResponse: "POST http://localhost:8080/server2_0_war_exploded/user returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error"
```

And the server error log

[2016-12-07T17:28:05.007+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1481128085007] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[MyApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet MyApplication threw exception
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 5 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:859)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
    at endpoints.UsersEndpoint.create(UsersEndpoint.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

Answer (score 0):

Your current code:

**Client side** (generate json text, encrypt it, and send):

```
    ClientResponse clientResponse = HttpRequests.post("/user/", Crypter.encryptDecryptXOR(new Gson().toJson(data)));
```

**Server side** (parse json, then decrypt):

```
String s = new Gson().fromJson(data,String.class);
String decrypt = Crypter.encryptDecryptXOR(s);
```

... looks like you should be decrypting **before** you try to parse the JSON data (hence the MalformedJsonException when parsing received json).

And by the way, `String.class` is probably not what you want the json content to be deserialized to (what about `User.class`?)

Edit:

For decryption, try something like:

```
String decrypted = Crypter.encryptDecryptXOR(data); 
SomeClass userData = new Gson().fromJson(decrypted, SomeClass.class);
```

*SomeClass* is a class that can accomodate the content of your json (User might be a good candidate, but you will need to check this).

Comment: Thank you for the answer :D

Can I ask you how you would write it ? 
I have tried to reverse it now, but cant quite make it work. I still get the same error.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide an example. If answer is still not clear for you, maybe you need to post a more specific question / edit the question, showing your new code. Try logging the arguments you are passing to the Gson.fromJson() method. Is this valid json content? Can the destination class accomodate this content (matching fields names / types, etc...)?